# Access Forbidden in Laravel after installing it on xampp

Tags: windows, laravel, installation, xampp

I have installed Laravel using [this guide](https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows), however whenever I go to laravel.dev I get "Access Forbidden". I have tried to give full access to everyone on every folder yet it doesn't work at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to edit the httpd-xampp.conf

from Require local to Require all granted in the LocationMatch tag.

That's it!

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">

        Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Didn't work ; there was no locationmatch tag so I added it myself like this: **<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require all granted
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>**

Comment: I don't think so :(

Comment: It has been almost a year, but I followed what he said and everything run well again AFAIK. If you check the edit time, he edited after the last message.

Answer (score 0):

Sent path which u used? He must be end by public. If this correct when try to write something test text in the .htaccess if u don't will be see 500 error than, u need write in the XAMP settings for this directory Override All